# wget downloads only 5 bytes file

Tags: 10.04, wget

I've got the following issue - the `wget` command downloads only 5bytes of files on the remote server I need to access.

I know, that the files have 5MB and 1.3MB, so why after wget'ing them i receive only 5b empty files?

===EDIT===

```
root@app:# wget -c -v XXX.X.X.XXX:139/dbase/dispense.log
--2013-03-28 09:10:27--  http://XXX.X.X.XXX:139/dbase/dispense.log
Connecting to XXX.X.X.XXX:139... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 No headers, assuming HTTP/0.9
Length: unspecified
Saving to: `dispense.log'

    [ <=>                                   ] 5           --.-K/s   in 0s

2013-03-28 09:10:27 (846 KB/s) - `dispense.log' saved [5]
```

Comment: Do you have this issue at all downloads or just at this downloads or this server?

Comment: `wget --no-check-certificate http://google.pl/images/srpr/logo4w.png` is working, so I suppose I have this problem only with that certain server

Comment: Can you give us the verbose output of the `wget` process fur such a download?

Comment: of course - added result to main post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wget` only supports HTTP, HTTPS and FTP protocols. You are using port 139 which is normally not a port such a protocol is run over.

If you're trying to download a file from a Samba/Windows network share, have a look at `mount.cifs`.